# Masking textbox to accept only 1 digit after decimal

Tags: textbox, vb6, masking

I am using VB6 and I want to allow user **to enter only one digit** after decimal,
please help.

Comment: What have you done so far? That would help to give you more accurate answer.

Comment: You have selected wrong tag `vba` you mean `vb` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code below in change event of textbox. I think "." point is used for decimal seperator. if "," coma is used, then change the point in the code with coma.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim strA As String
Dim intP As Integer

    strA = TextBox1.Text
    intP = InStr(1, strA, ".", vbTextCompare)

    If intP > 0 Then TextBox1.Text = Left(strA, intP + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible to get the local decimal symbol. http://programmer-collection.blogspot.com/2008/12/vb6-get-decimal-separator-and-digit.html